# autowiring servletContext vs implementing servletContextAware

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I have seen two ways of getting the `servletContext` bean in the service/controller.

1) simple way is just autowiring:

```
@Autowired
ServletContext servletContext;
```

2) the other way is to implement the `servletContextAware` interface:

```
@RestController("/mycontroller")
public myController implements ServletContextAware {

    private ServletContext context;

    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

   public String getContextPath(){
   return context.getContextPath();
  }

}
```

What are the pros and cons of these two? Which is the recommended way?

Comment: Questions like this will mainly attacked opinionated answers.

Comment: As long as it constructive, it is good. thats why SO and not some random forums?

Comment: I've found that while migrating from XML config to Java config, classes that have the `@Autowired` ServletContext may fail on startup.  One remedy to this would be to implement `ServletContextAware` in those cases.

Answer (score -3):

No one has answered so I'll give it a go.

The annotation version is simpler but in cases when autowiring isn't enabled (or in Spring versions prior to this functionality) then only the `ServletContextAware` version will work.

The recommended way is the former if you have that functionality enabled.

Comment: Entirely opinion based.  I actually prefer to not use the annotations because that's Spring concepts leaking into your class.